# Make Connections From One Location In PHP

Tags: php, database-connection

In JSP, if I want to connect to the database, I would create a Java class called DBManager with the following code:

```
public class DBManager {
    private final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    private final static String DB_USERNAME = "root";
    private final static String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
    public static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    /**
     * Tests connection with the database by getting connection using the
     * database url and username and password. And creates a dumb statement and
     * closes it to make sure everything is working fine.
     */
     static {
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Now, I can easily do something like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = DBManager.conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER");
```

I'm learning PHP on my own and "most" of the online tutorials actually don't teach how to do stuff the right way.

They all do it in the traditional way in each page they need a connection:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Which is wrong because say you want to change your password? Then, you have to change it in each and every page that you used that password.

My question: how can I do something equivalent/similar to that Java class in PHP?

EDIT:

```
<?php 
class DBManager {
   public static $conn = null;
   private static $hostname = "localhost";
   private static $username = "root";
   private static $password = "root";
   private static $dbname = "tutorme";

   protected function __construct() {
       try {
           DBManager::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tutorme", DBManager::$username, DBManager::$password);
           DBManager::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === DBManager::$conn) {
            DBManager::$conn = new DBManager();
        }
       return DBManager::$conn;
   }
}
?>
```

I searched a little and came up with the above code. However, now when I call

```
$stmt = DBManager::getInstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO SUBJECT (SubjectTitle, SubjectName) VALUES (:subject,:subj)");
```

I get an error that there's no function in `DBManager` called `prepare()`

which means that my `DBManager::getInstance` is returning a `DBManager object` instead of `PDO conn object`

Comment: I don't know which tutorials you have looked at but there a far better ones out there forexample: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g

Comment: Obviously you are not meant to store the credentials in each and every file. Those examples you mention are simplified _examples_ meant to show in general how things work. The authors trust in the reader being able to find out by himself that the credentials can be included or imported like any other piece of your application too. not everything you do not get right at first sight is automatically "sucking" (to use your words). Instead you should say "thanks" to those authors who put their spare time into writing something you can benefit from. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha +1 edited the post. What I actually meant is that I have never seen a tutorial which teaches you about `PreparedStatement` instead of a normal `Statement` for example.

Comment: I do not see what that has to do with storing credentials in each file. That is a totally separate thing. But even so, what _is_ your point? There are about 6683738567393 examples for using prepared statements with `mysqli` or `PDO` alone here on SO, much more on google. But actually things are much easier for you: why don't you simply read the documentation? It comes with exactly the examples about prepared statements you miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one obvious mistake:

`DBManager::$conn = new DBManager();`

You don't want that!

Just call `new DBManager()` and the `$conn` var will be initiliazed!

And also here are some minor changes,

```
<?php 
class DBManager {
    public static $conn = null;
    private static $hostname = "localhost";
    private static $username = "root";
    private static $password = "root";
    private static $dbname = "tutorme";

    private function __construct() {
        try { // why not using $hostname and $dbname?!
           DBManager::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBManager::$hostname . ";dbname=" .DBManager::$dbname, DBManager::$username, DBManager::$password);
           DBManager::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // getConnection() is a better naming of the function
    public static function getConnection() {
        if (is_null(DBManager::$conn)) {
            new DBManager();
       }
       // now $conn is initialized
       return DBManager::$conn;
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't see that at all!! I wondered why the heck `getInstance()` was returning `DBManager` object...

Answer (score 0):

make a class just like what's in java and let's call it `database.php`

in the file u want to do something

```
include 'database.php';
.... your code .....
```

tip: look for "autoload"

is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

you can start off with this

```
class Database{
    function __construct(){
        $this->host = HOST;
        $this->user = DB_USER;
        $this->pass = DB_PASS;
        $this->db = DATABASE;
        $this->con = $this->connect();
    }

    function connect(){
        $q = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        if($q) return $q; die("Couldn't Connect to Database");
    }
}
```

other file like so for example

```
include 'Database.php';
$db = new Database();
mysqli_query($db->con, "QUERY_HERE");
```